# Не получается настроить алиасы в vesta CP

Tags: nginx, apache, администрирование, ispmanager, vesta

В общем есть сайт, который переношу с хостинга на отдельный сервер. На старом хостинге стоит isp manager. Сайт работает на HostCMS и имеет поддомены по городам. В isp эти поддомены выглядят просто как алиасы к основному домену. На новом сервере поставил vesta cp, основной домен работает без проблем, прописал поддомены так же алиасами к основному, но при попытке их открыть открывается не нужный сайт, а технический домен нового хостинга, который создался при установке vesta. В чем может быть проблема? Как настроить vesta так чтобы алиасы домена открывали именно нужный сайт?
Дополнение.
Удалил служебный домен, поддомены совсем перестали открываться

Comment: C vesta cp, после обновления, что то случилось и алиасы у меня пропали. Я хз чего делать?